# How to use Bootstrap Mixins with Sass rather than Less?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, less, mixins

I first experienced using Bootstrap mixins like `@include border-radius(5px);` in a rails app that uses Sass/Scss and bootstrap-sass https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass

This was a great experience, as I was able to use many bootstrap mixins without needing to migrate to/learn LESS, which bootstrap suggests if you would like to enable mixins in your app: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/extend.html

I now am working on a non-rails app, but would like to still use bootstrap mixins with SASS, rather than LESS. Does anyone know of a library or bootstrap sass mixins for non-rails apps?

If it is relevant, I'm using django in the new app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Bootstrap now has an official Sass port, available here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

**PREVIOUS**

I found a version of bootstrap written in sass, much easier than installing ruby/compass/bootstrap-sass onto system running a non-rails app.

https://www.github.com/jlong/sass-twitter-bootstrap

I copied out the lib from sass-twitter-bootstrap and just attached the main sass file "bootstrap.scss".

done! no need to install anything extra on any system that can already handle sass.

Comment: Bootstrap now has an [official Sass port](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass), which should be used instead of the link in the answer above.

Comment: @Chris thanks, I'll update this answer.